# Rails add new view to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have generated  views with this command after I installed devise

```
rails generate devise:views
```

and I override registration controller by

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def sign_up2

  end
end
```

And updated routes.rb with

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

I expected to see a new route/view of

```
  /users/sign_up2
```

but I don't see it
And here routes for devise

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
```

But I would like a new view and route

**Update**:
issue when I load view

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

in this line

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,:html => { :class => "form-horizontal col-sm-12",:role=>"form"}, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: What view and route do you want to add?

Comment: Understood. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke a `devise_scope` block and declare your custom route within:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }  
devise_scope :user do
  get "users/sign_up2"=> "users/registrations#sign_up2", :as => "sign_up2_registration"
end
```

The section on [Configuring routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in the documentation provides the following explanation of `devise_scope`:

> If you have the need for more deep customization, for instance to also allow "/sign_in" besides "/users/sign_in", all you need to do is to create your routes normally and wrap them in a devise_scope block in the router

Previously, Devise allowed custom routes to be passed as a block to `devise_for`, but [this behavior has been deprecated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1615).

**UPDATE**:

To address the `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` error, you need to ensure that your custom `sign_up2` action is properly setting the `resource` variable. Assuming you want to mimic the `registrations/new` action, you can do something akin to the following:

```
def sign_up2
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
end
```

This ensures that the `resource` variable in your view is not `nil` and will not throw the exception you're currently witnessing.

*Alternatively*, depending on the behavior you're trying to evince, you can set your own instance variable in the custom controller action, then pass it as the resource to your `form_for` tag:

```
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
def sign_up_2
    @new_registrant = Registrant.new
end

# app/views/users/sign_up2.html.erb
<%= form_for(@new_registrant, :as => resource_name,:html => { :class => "form-horizontal col-sm-12",:role=>"form"}, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

*However*, if you follow this approach, you should consider *why* you need to roll this into Devise. Devise, by default, assigns the `resource` variable via the `build_resource` function. If you're going to override/bypass this function, you should consider abstracting this entire functionality out of Devise since you're totally circumventing its default behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can load the view now but with a slight problem, Could you help with?

Comment: What is your problem? Also, if this answer has addressed your original question, please accept it as correct.

Comment: See my update. If it addresses your question in full, please accept this answer as correct.