# using devise with separate user profile (users#show) and profile_update (users#update), routing issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am thoroughly confused.  I am using the devise gem for user authentication.  How do I appropriately set-up a separate `user_profile.html.erb` and `user_profile_update.html.erb` page - while keeping `devise/registrations#edit` to manage a user's password.  The current user profile view renders properly.  However, the user_profile_update won't save.  And I get the error: No route matches [PATCH] "/user/1".  These routes are listed (twice!) when I run rake routes.  However, while the put and patch routes are there, there's no path statement to them.

```
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT     /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
```

I was getting a "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error; however, I moved passed it by explicitly declaring the user as:

```
@user = User.find(:user => params[:id])
```

See this, if interested: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2451  in why the issue exists with devise and forms.  The "form", incidentally, is only called once - another error I resolved with help: [form_for renders get rather than post, using rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810731/form-for-renders-get-rather-than-post-using-rails)

Here's the current set-up:

1. In the `app/views/users/registrations` folder are new and edit which
   are routed to `devise/registrations#new` and
   `devise/registrations#edit`.  When a new user registers, we only collect - per devise - their :email and :password.  Their :id is assigned by the database.  After registering, we ask users to complete their profile by going to `user_update_profile.html.erb`
2. The users/controller:

   ```
   def new
     @user = User.new
   end

   def create
     @user = User.new
     @user.save
     if user_signed_in?
       @user = User.find(:user => params[:id])
       @user.save    
     flash[:success] = "User Profile Updated!"
     redirect_to user_profile_path
     end
   end

   def user_profile
     @user = User.find(:user => params[:id])
     @user.save
     if user_signed_in?
       @user = current_use
       @user.save     
     end
   end

   def update
     @user = User.find(:user => params[:id])
     @user.save          
     if user_signed_in?
       @user = current_user
       @user.save
     end
   end

   def user_profile_update
     @user = User.find(:user => params[:id])
     @user.save
     if user_signed_in?
       @user = current_user
       @user.save
     end
   end
   ```

   There are probably a few extra `@user.save`s in there!  I'll refactor after I get it
   working.
3. The top of the form `user_profile_update.html.erb`:

   ```
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <div> 
     <div>  
     <%= form_for(@user, url: user_profile_update_path, html: { method: :patch }) 
     do |f| %>
   ```

   I've tried using both 'put' and 'patch'.
4. In config/routes:

   ```
   #DEVISE
   authenticated :user do
   resources :user,  only: [:user_profile_update, :user_profile, :destroy]
   end

   # USER
   devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users" }
   resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update]

   get 'user_profile'                    =>  'users#user_profile'
   match 'user_profile_update',          to: 'users#update', via: 'patch'
   ```

Do I have a simple routing error?  (I suspect it has to do with `users#show` and `users#update` views; however, I'm out of ideas of what to try.)

Or is my issue devise?  Do I need to create a separate devise controller with scope as users [ https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers ] and create a scope block [ https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes ].  See this SO question and excellent answer: [Rails add new view to devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599714/rails-add-new-view-to-devise)  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You say `No route matches [PATCH] "/user/1"`, and then you show `"/users/:id"` in your routes. Look carefully to see the difference.

Comment: The `put` and `patch` routes are there; however, there's no path statement to them.  Also, `@user = User.find(:user => params[:id])` is breaking, i.e., showing as an error when I try to access the `user_profile.html.erb` - so I removed it.

Comment: @zeantsoi Re SO question: 27879118 Should I be following your earlier directions re devise?  Or do I have a simple routing error?  Thanks!

Comment: @zeantsoi - It was a routing error.  Thanks for giving me a shoulder to cry on!  Two days+ wasted!  Your answer to the other question really helped.

Answer (score 0):

It was a routing error - caused, I think, by a conflict between `def update` and `def user_profile_update`.